# Count multiple terms

Tags: django

```
class Term(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   
    term = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Hey Guys, 
I try to Count duplicate/multiple terms from my db table but I get still a list of all items (`{term: a, count: 1, term: a, count: 1,term: b, count: 1,...}`) of my table and not like `{term: a, count: 12, term: b, count: 1}`

Has anyone an idea?

EDIT:

```
ee = Term.objects.annotate(Count("term")).values("term", "term__count")
```

Result:

```
[{'term': u'tes', 'term__count': 1}, {'term': u'tes', 'term__count': 1},
```

What I expected:

```
[{'term': u'tes', 'term__count': 2},  {'term': 'b', 'term__count': 1}
```

Comment: What did you try? How did you get that list? What is `count`?

Comment: I use the count method from django

Comment: Can you post your code, where you're using the "count method from django"?

Comment: I added some code snippet

Comment: Fixed a mistake in my snippet should show the count

Comment: You are annotating whilst you should be aggregating.

Comment: Aggregates returns only a dict with the aggregated value, not the raws themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/
says about the order being important.  Also, if you have an order_by on the model, that will affect it.
How about ...

```
ee = Term.objects.values("term").annotate(Count("term")).order_by()
```

Comment: Django officiel documentation about annotate: "Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of aggregate values (averages, sums, etc) that have been computed __over the objects that are related to the objects in the QuerySet__. " the term charfield is not a related object no ? We don't seem to be in the scope of the annotate() function no ?!

Comment: @Ricola3D.  It works for me even where the field in question is not a foreign key field, (e.g. just a boolean).  (As I said, if I didn't include .order_by() on the end of it, the model's own order_by settings would cause a problem that makes it include a separate element for each instance.)

Comment: Ah okay, that's really ugly but that's usefull to avoid dirty raw SQL in python code !

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you cannot do that in only one query, you need a sub query. I guess it is the same with Django, so try this:

```
ee = Term.objects.extra(select={'count': "SELECT COUNT(term) FROM appname_term AS subtable WHERE subtable.term = appname_term.term"})
```

It should add a count attribute to every term from ee with the number of rows with this. It applies a subquery on the same relation in the main query. It's equivalent of SQL:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT COUNT(term) 
    FROM appname_term AS subtable
    WHERE subtable.term = appname_term.term
) AS count
FROM appname_term
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use raw SQL when Django's ORM provides a perfectly valid way to do this. Check jcfollower's answer.

Comment: Is there really something in Django ORM to do this ? Django's official documentation about "annotate" tells: "Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of aggregate values (averages, sums, etc) that have been computed __over the objects that are related to the objects in the QuerySet__." It says is works for relations between table, not for a row of this same table. That's why 1 is always returned as count !

Comment: That's why you need to use `values()` _before_ `annotate()`. Otherwise, you count the number of occurances of each unique row - and each row has a unique id, so it's 1. If you use `values('tem').annotate()` you first select just the 'term' values and do a SQL GROUP BY statement before you count - gettting exactly the results you want. The only reason the documentation is just about related fields is becuase none of the annotate functions make any sense on the same table if you don't use `values()` before it. It does actually work just as expected on fields of the same table.